# Qt: prevent the mouse from moving outside a QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, mouse, mousemove, qgraphicsscene

I would like to prevent the mouse from moving outside a `QGraphicsScene` if the mouse is pressed.

I tried to use `QCursor::setPos ( 0, 0)` for example but it is using the screen coordinates. So I think I need to map the coordinates into the scene. I know that `QWidget::mapToGlobal()` already exists.

Does someone know how to restrict movable area of the mouse into a `QGraphicsScene` please?

Comment: I tried to use `parent->mapToGlobal(p)` then `QtCursor::setPos(p)` with `p` declared before like that `QPoint p; p.setX(100); p.setY(0);`. But it returns the mouse at the position (100,0) of the screen not in the coordinates of the `QWidget`. Any ideas why please?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution if someone has one...